# Replacing missing data with a number in python

Tags: python

I have a tab-delimited file like this,

```
Acc Pop snp1 snp2 snp3 snp4 snp5
a1  pop1    0   1   0   1   0
a2  pop1    0   1           0
a3  pop1    0   1   0   0   0
a4  pop1    0   1   0   1   0
a5  pop1    0   1   0       0
a6  pop1        1   0   0   0
a7  pop1    0   1   0   0   0
a8  pop1    0   1   0   0   0
a9  pop1    0   1   0       
a10 pop1    0   1   0   0   1
```

I need to replace all missing data with '-9'. So the output looks like this,

```
Acc Pop snp1 snp2 snp3 snp4 snp5
a1  pop1    0   1   0   1   0
a2  pop1    0   1   -9 -9   0
a3  pop1    0   1   0   0   0
a4  pop1    0   1   0   1   0
a5  pop1    0   1   0   -9  0
a6  pop1    -9  1   0   0   0
a7  pop1    0   1   0   0   0
a8  pop1    0   1   0   0   0
a9  pop1    0   1   0   -9  -9
a10 pop1    0   1   0   0   1
```

This is my try below,

```
import re
infilename = 'file2.txt'
outfilename = 'file.txt'
regex = re.compile(r"\s+")    

with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
        outfile.write(regex.sub('-9', line))
```

Comment: Please add to your question which error you get. (in your case: `TypeError: expected string or buffer` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it.

When you do a split you get a list of items so you can't do a regex on them.

Instead iterate trough the list and simply replace value with -9 if there is none set.

```
import re
infilename = 'file2.txt'
outfilename = 'file.txt'

with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
        line = [val if val else '-9' for val in line]
        outfile.write('\t'.join(line) + '\n')
```

remember, this will replace all 'blank' fields in the table, even one's in the header.

Comment: one-line statement. That's really practical. +1